# Listview crashes when I scroll down or up

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Basically i have an sqlite database which allows to me insert hotel images with titles. Previously I had a problem,as I was getting duplicate images shown in the list,but thank God,I fixed it. Now the images are shown fine. However when I scroll down or up the listview,the app crashes.

Here is how I initialize the custom adapter.

```
        adapter = new HotelArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_row,
            imageArry);
        ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And that's how I am design it overriding the getView() method.

```
        public class HotelArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hotels> {
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
         ArrayList<Hotels> data = new ArrayList<Hotels>();
         public HotelArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<Hotels> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
       }
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = convertView;

        ImageHolder holder = null;

        if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)     
        ((Activity)context).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

        holder = new ImageHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        holder.imgIcon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconView);
    }
        Hotels picture = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(picture._name);
        //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

        byte[] outImage=picture._image;
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    return row;
   }
    static class ImageHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

 }
```

and finally the output of the logcat is
             12-12 19:43:20.665: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1183): java.lang.NullPointerException

```
         12-12 19:43:20.665: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1183):  at 
         athens.tourist.guide.HotelArrayAdapter.getView(HotelArrayAdapter.java:44)

         12-12 19:43:20.665: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1183):  at 
         athens.tourist.guide.HotelArrayAdapter.getView(HotelArrayAdapter.java:44)
         12-12 19:43:20.665: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1183):  at   
         android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)

         12-12 19:43:20.665: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1183):  at  
         android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)

         12-12 19:43:20.665: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1183):  at 
         android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:708)
```

Comment: What is the line 44 of HotelArrayAdapter?

Comment: holder.txtTitle.setText(picture._name); this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application crashes because the `convertView` is null just once. Try to store the holder object as convertView's tag, and retrieve it afterwards. e.g

```
ImageHolder holder = null;

if(row==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)     
    ((Activity)context).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

    holder = new ImageHolder();
    holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
    holder.imgIcon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconView);
    row.setTag(holder);
} 
holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is when **row is not null, you never initialize the holder** so, this is null and launch a *NullPointerException*.

Try to change this fragment of code:

```
ImageHolder holder = null;

if(row==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)     
       ((Activity)context).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

  holder = new ImageHolder();
  holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
  holder.imgIcon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconView);
}
```

For this other:

```
ImageHolder holder = null;

if(row==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)     
       ((Activity)context).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

  holder = new ImageHolder();
  holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
  holder.imgIcon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconView);
  row.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
}
```

Comment: You have copy this code well? Add at the end of the if the row.setTag(holder), is important